# How to use serializeObject() with require.js Error: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, requirejs

How can I use the script below which exstends jquery $.fn.serializeObject() with require.js?

I'm getting the following error:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined serializeObject.js:
(anonymous function)**

```
   $.fn.serializeObject = function() {
      var o = {};
      var a = this.serializeArray();
      $.each(a, function() {
          if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
              if (!o[this.name].push) {
                  o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
              }
              o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
          } else {
              o[this.name] = this.value || '';
          }
      });
      return o;
    };
```

this is my view save function giving the error:

```
 var participantDetails = $(ev.currentTarget).serializeObject();
```

does it need some other dependance I have missed?

This is my main.js:

```
require.config({

  shim: {

   "jquery": {
        exports: '$'
    },

    underscore: {
      exports: '_'
    },
    backbone: {
      deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
      exports: 'Backbone',
      init: function (_, $) { Backbone.$ = $; return Backbone; }
    },
    backbone_tastypie: {
      deps: ['backbone',  'underscore', 'jquery'],
      attach: "Backbone"
    },
     serialize: {
      deps: ['jquery']
      //exports: 'jQuery.fn.serializeObject'
    }
  },
  paths: {
    jquery: '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min',
    underscore: '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.5.2/underscore-min',
    backbone: '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.1.0/backbone-min',
    backbone_tastypie: '/static/js/libs/backbone-tastypie',
    serialize: '/static/js/libs/serializeObject',
    text: 'text',
    templates: '/static/'

  }

});

require([
  'app'
], function(App){

  App.initialize();

});
```

Comment: Are you sure ``$`` is defined (script library loaded) *before* you run this piece of js?

Comment: ^^^ This and also you create a function called `serializeObject` and then try to run it as `serialize_object()`

Comment: Also, the jQuery URL (I didn't try any of the others) gives a 403 forbidden error.

Comment: sorry @Archer updated question mistype. I'm using serializeObject()

Comment: @Archer there is nothing wrong with the path http/https get appended. Jquery seems to work fine in my views. I just cannot seems to use serializeObject()

Comment: Thanks @Spike, but I understand how protocol relative URLs work.  The problem that I'm seeing is that the jQuery URL returns a 403 forbidden error which would mean you're not actually loading jQuery, which could then lead to the error that you are getting.

Comment: @Archer o thats strange as jquery seems to be available in my views I'll check that out

Comment: It may not be the issue at hand, but it will obviously be an issue for some of your users, even if it works okay for you.  I'd recommend using the Google CDN where possible as it's probably the most commonly used.

Comment: @Archer I see, yes I checked it out and on my network tab jquery is loading 200 ok but as you stated giving 403 if I use externally.  serializeObject still does not have access to jquery and think this is a require.js issue. any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you defining a module? You need to:

```
define([
  'jquery'
],

etc
```